# C++ with OpenGL - Drawing a square

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I have to make a program that should draw a square that change colors.
This program will draw window with a white background, the dimensions of 256x256 pixels, a red square with upper left vertex coordinate (x, y) = (30, 226) and lower right corner coordinates (x, y) = (226 , 30). When the key 'a' (keycode = 97) is pressed, the square should stick with the color blue. When the 'v' key (keycode = 118) is pressed, the square should go back to red. When the ESC key (keycode = 27) is pressed the program should be terminated.

-- There is the log...

```
Build Log     
Build started: 
Project: square, Configuration: Debug|Win32

Command Lines      
Creating temporary file "c:\Users\TEMP\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\square\square\Debug\RSP00000544445896.rsp" with contents
[
/OUT:"C:\Users\TEMP\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\square\Debug\square.exe" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\square.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\TEMP\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\square\Debug\square.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

".\Debug\square.obj"
]
Creating command line "link.exe @"c:\Users\TEMP\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\square\square\Debug\RSP00000544445896.rsp" /NOLOGO /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT"


Output Window    
Linking...
square.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____glutInitWithExit@12 referenced in function _glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK@8
square.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8 referenced in function _glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK@4
C:\Users\TEMP\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\square\Debug\square.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals


 Results     
 Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\TEMP\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\square\square\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
square - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

// Function callback that is called to manage the keyboard tasks
float r = 0.0f;
float g = 0.0f;
float b = 0.0f;
void GerenciaTeclado(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case 'a':// change the actual color to red
        r = 1.0f;
        g = 0.0f;
        b = 0.0f;
        break;
    case 'v':// change de color to blue
        r = 0.0f;
        g = 0.0f;
        b = 1.0f;
        break;
    case 27:// close the screen
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

// Function callback that is called to draw
void Desenha(void)
{
    // Clean the window
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Initializes the coordinates system
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    double ar = w / h;
    glOrtho( -2 * ar, 2 * ar, -2, 2, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Draw a square
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Shows that the color is red
    //        R  G  B
    glColor3f(r, g, b);
    glVertex2f(-1, -1);
    glVertex2f( 1, -1);
    // Shows that the color is blue
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f( 1, 1);
    glVertex2f(-1, 1);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

// Main Program
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(256,256);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);
    glutCreateWindow("Quadrado");
    glutDisplayFunc(Desenha);
    glutKeyboardFunc(GerenciaTeclado);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Always post your error when you have one. No one is supposed to be able to guess it out of the blue.

Comment: I've added the image of the error now... Thanks so much.

Comment: A copy and paste into the question would have been better. Anyway now that you posted it I see that you have a **linker** error so your code did compile. It did not link.

Comment: That's ok... I've posted the log that was created. Thanks so much. But that linker error that you mentioned... What that does mean? So the problem isn't with my code?

Comment: I believe you have problem linking with `glut.h`. Check for the documentation of the library on how to link it with program.

Comment: Using deprecated OpenGL methods is not so good too!!

Answer (score 1):

When building something with GLUT you need to link your code with glut library. Try to google how do you link a visual studio with additional third party library. In your case I believe you will need to add another library directory and than add an additional dependency(glut.lib) in the project linker properties.